# ASP.net Membership without Username

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'd like configure asp.net's template membership provider and I want to use it with unique email address instead of username. I don't need username section. How can I do this?

Comment: Just store an email address instead of the username.  There is nothing restricting you that says it has to be a username.  This is the easiest way without modifying the provider.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the email as username to [`Membership.CreateUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8yy6w3h.aspx):

```
Membership.CreateUser(email, password, email);
```

[`MembershipProvider.RequiresUniqueEmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.requiresuniqueemail.aspx) is `true` by default, so that's not the problem.